# Pushing one UIViewController from one UINavigationController on to a different UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavagationController` (NC) that displays numerous `UIViewController` (VC) Views for an array of "Items", and I have a `UINavigationController` that displays numerous `UIViewController` Views for an array of "owners".  Users can scroll through the items, select one, and then view the corresponding owner (and vice versa).  Since the owner VC is on a different NC than the item NC, I get a "nested animation can result in corrupted navigation bar"  and "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions".

How do I push a view that is a member of another NC to a different NC?

Answer (score 1):

Each navigation controller has a `viewControllers` property:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers
```

This is just an array of all the view controllers in that navigation controllers stack.  When you "push a view that is a member of another NC to a different NC", you could first remove that view controller from the first navigation controller's `viewControllers` array before pushing that same view controller onto the second navigation controller's stack.

Comment: Incidentally, how are these two navigation controllers laid out?  Are the visible at the same time?  For instance, with the first NC on the left side of the screen and the second NC on the right side of the screen?

Comment: These are not on the screen at the same time, they are just in different tabs.  So I need to go back and remove my VC from the original NC and then add it to the other NC?  Does that mean that I need to make my VC a global property in order to remove it from my new NC?